# C++ Inheritance & composition used together

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, composite

I have class A, having methods that update properties of B. So, I need inheritance.

```
class B{
public:
int x;
};

class A : public B{
public:
void update(int y){
x = y;
}
};
```

I also want to reach function "update" through class B, so I also need composition.

```
class B{
public:
A a;
int x;
};

class A : public B{
public:
void update(int y){
x = y;
}
};
```

I want my structure as such, so that I want to track properties of objects-type Bs this way:

```
...
B.a.update(5);
int n = B.x;
```

However, I cannot use composition before declaring class A,  and cannot use inheritance before declaring class B. What should I do to resolve this infinite loop ?

Comment: Your example code won't work as it is, you cannot call a function update() on B.a and assign it to an int. You'd have to define a conversion operator to do that.

Comment: bennofs; object "a" is type "A", having a method named update, so you can do that actually.

Comment: @crowder: `B` is not an `A`.  Other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here, but if I'm guessing correctly, what you might need is a virtual function:

```
class B{
public:
int B;
virtual void update(int x){
    B = x;
}
};

class A : public B{
public:
virtual void update(int x){
    // Here goes code specific to B-class.
    B::update(x);
    // or here ;)
}
};
```

btw, you probably don't want `int B` field in a `public:` section; if you modify it's value from `update` method, you probably don't want others to try to modify it directly.

Comment: OK, I want to update B's properties THROUGH A, but I also want to reach those methods THROUGH B; thats what I want to achieve at last.

Comment: @C.CanberkBacı:  `virtual` functions are how you do this.

Comment: Square is a Rectangle -> is-a -> use inheritance
Car has a Window -> has-a -> use composition

that was what "thinking in C++" book offered me, so I was confused about my case, as if it was not possible. Thanks

Comment: @C. Canberk -  Square IS NOT a rectangle!!!  Squareness is a predicate of a rectangle.  It's a rectangle with equal width and height. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

Comment: Yeah, it is square-polygon or car-vehicle relationship, my bad.