# Object oriented design issue in C++

Tags: c++, oop, object-oriented-analysis

Suppose I have a car, having an engine and a radio. I want to start the radio when engine starts, and want to destroy car when engine is over a certain temperature. In the book **Thinking in C++**, there was a composition example that helped me out. My idea was similar:

```
class Engine
{
public:
    int temperature;
    void start()
    {
        temperature = 15
    }

    void rev()
    {
        temperature += 2;
    }
}

class Radio
{
public:
    void open() {}
}

class Car
{
public:
    ~Car();
    Engine engine;
    Radio radio;
}
```

I know I can manually implement:

```
main()
{
    Car car;
    car.engine.start();
    car.radio.open();
    while(car != NULL)
    {
        car.engine.rev();
        if(car.engine.temperature > 50)
        {
            delete(&car);
        }
    }
}
```

I may have syntax errors, it's not important. My question is: How can I create all the communication between classes automatically, so that

```
main()
{
    Car car;
    while(car!= NULL)
    {
        car.engine.rev();
    }
```

does the same job? I also tried inheritance and virtual functions to create the communication, but failed.

Comment: I would recommend, for better readability, that you use the standard naming convention which is to start *class names* with an uppercase letter, and *object names* with a lowercase letter (you are doing the contrary, that by the way confuses the syntax highlighter of SO).

Comment: Not to mention code formatting is for humans!

Comment: sorry, edited just now

Comment: Also, to give you another good practice, it is not the user of a `Car` that should call `car.engine.start()`, since this user is not meant to know how an engine work. Instead, you should write this in a method of Car: `Car::start() { engine.start(); }`. Hence, you call directly `car.start()`. This is also what you do in real life. You know how to start a car: by turning the key. Once you do this, the car knows how to actually ignites the engine, but it is not you as a driver that acts directly on the engine. It may look like a lot of typing for nothing, but it actually makes your code better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Observer pattern

You could use an Observer pattern, which provides a general way for the Engine to pass a notification to an arbitrary interested party (often you'd allow multiple observers who'd all be notified, but for this purpose supporting one is enough).

```
struct IEngineObserver
{
    virtual void on_overheated() = 0;
};

class Engine
{
  public:
    Engine(IEngineObserver& observer) : observer_(observer) { }

    void start()
    {
        temperature_ = 15;
    }
    void rev()
    {
        if ((temperature_ += 2) > 50)
            on_overheated();
    }
    IEngineObserver& observer_;
    int temperature_;
};

class Radio
{
  public:
    void open() {}
};

class Car : public IEngineObserver
{
  public:
    Car() : engine_(this), finito_(false) { }
    ~Car();
    virtual void on_overheat() override { finito_ = true; }
    Engine engine_;
    Radio radio_;
    bool finito_;
};
```

You can then loop until `car.finito_` is `true`.  It doesn't make sense to `delete` the Car from within the Engine though, if you have some code in `main()` continually invoking operations on the Car object... that will crash.  The `Car` will be destroyed when it goes out of scope at the end of `main`, so your focus should be on breaking out of the `rev()`ing loop at the right time - i.e. when `finito_` is set.

### Lambda and std::function

Something similar can be done with lambdas and `std::function`, so that the Car can specify arbitrary code for the engine to run when it overheats as in...

```
    Car() : engine_([&] () { finito_ = true; }), finito_(false) { }

    Engine(std::function<void (*)()>& f) : f_(f) { }
```

...without needing an extra `IEngineObserver` class or `on_overheat` functions.

Comment: While generally a good answer, this is very much over-engineering for OP and definitely not what he needs. He needs to learn the basics of OO; this solution is way down the road.

Comment: @Lstor: that might be true, but you've tried that and he's quipped "thanks, but is there a way to make this dependency fully automatic? So that when engine is overheated, state of the car is set (without calling isWorking method)." -> I'm just addressing his question, which I think is reasonable on SO even if advising something simpler based on his current ability, and for other readers.

Comment: That's the best way of doing it indeed.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing a couple of issues. First of all, you say you want to `delete` a class from within itself. That is normally not a good idea.

The key here is that there is a difference between allocating and deallocating memory, and having a valid object. You could have a `bool overheated` variable in your class that you will set to `true` when the `Car` overheats. Then your loop can look like this:

```
class Engine {
private:
    bool overheated;
public:
    bool isOverheated() const { return overheated; }
    void rev();

    // Rest of implementation ...
};

void Engine::rev() {
    temperature += 2;
    if (temperature > 50) overheated = true; 
}

class Car { /* ... */ };

int main() {
    Car car;
    while (!car.engine.isOverheated()) {
        car.engine.rev();
    }
}
```

Using `NULL`, `delete` and so on is related to memory allocation. For a class like this, you should normally separate concerns. Memory allocation (stack vs. heap) is one thing, and whether the object is in a correct state or not is another.

**Edit:**

If you want the `Car`'s state to be dependent on the `Engine`'s, then just do like this:

```
class Car {
    Engine engine;
public:
    bool isWorking() const { return !engine.isOverheated(); }
};
```

Comment: `you want to delete a class from within itself. That is not possible.`: This is incorrect. it is perfectly legal (and sometimes useful) to invoke `delete this`. Of course, any further call from within the method performing this statement would be Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if that was actually true. I changed the wording.

Comment: well, totally understood the concept. State tracking is important. However, I want the rev() method is callable from the engine object, which should be declared under the car object: car.engine.rev(); Then, this should change car's state, not the engine's. And that is where I am confused, since you cannot set the state of another class, without inheriting it. And I cannot add inheritance because of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327081/c-inheritance-composition-used-together).

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to make this dependency fully automatic? So that when engine is overheated, state of the car is set (without calling isWorking method).

Comment: In this example, it is per se fully automatic, because the state of the car *is* the state of the engine. To change a variable in `Car` when the `Engine` is overheated would be a lot more complex. That approach is over-engineering and a poor design.

Comment: The thing is that you want to *encapsulate* the inner workings of the car. Those who use a `Car` don't need to know how it works, because that would add dependencies, which is bad. Therefore, it is much better to have users of `Car` call `isWorking()` than to have them access a member variable.

Comment: +1 with the edit. I still posted another answer for the sake of completeness, but yours is the most useful IMHO.

Comment: @C.CanberkBacı I think you misunderstood an important concept of OOP: the *state* of an object is not related to its actual bytes stored as part of the object, but rather to what is accessible through its **public methods**. Here, the good practice would be to have `Engine` a private member, and have `revEngine()` and `isWorking()` the only public methods of `car`. Hence, a user using a `car` doesn't have to know what an `engine` is. As in real life.

Answer (score 2):

### First of all

There are many wrong things in your approach,

Most important (I think) : you seem to confuse the notion of pointer to a dynamically allocated object and local declared object. In your code `Car car;` is not a pointer. Therefore it cannot be `NULL` and you can't delete it.

I show you with an exemple

```
int main()
{
  // this is a pointer unitialized, so it points a random place in memory
  // (depending on what was in memory before) 
  Car * car;
  
  // initialization at NULL
  // the pointer points to NULL, i.e no object
  car = NULL;   

  // a car object is created in memory and the pointer `car` now points on it
  car = new car();

  // do things with your object through the pointer
  car->engine.start();
  
  // the car object is deleted from memory and Car points to NULL
  delete(car);
   
  return 0;
}
```

Now without pointers (which is a better way to do things in C++)

```
int main()
{
   // car is a local object, it is automatically created by calling the default
   // constructor
   Car car;

   // do things with your object
   car.engine.start();

   return 0;
   
} // <- the oject is automatically destroyed when you go out of the scope
```

My example is surely not exhaustive about the difference between pointer and local object. I strongly recommand you to read more about Oriented Object Programming and Its notions (such as encapsulation, because in your case it's not good too).

And keep in mind that C++ does not the things the way others OO languages can do, like java for example where every Object variable works like a pointer.

### However

Concerning your original problem about behavior of objects and relationship between them, the answer of Lstor is a good exemple of how a OO design can look like.
But I think you have misunderstooding on OO programming that lead you to that kind of bad design, thus my advice is to read (or carefully re read, or choose another book) more on OO programming in C++

Comment: Feel free to be a good example and put the missing `int` before `main()` too :)

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible*, even though not recommended in the general case, to delete an object from within itself. You can do it like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    void commitSuicide()
    { 
        delete this; 
    }
}
```

However, in your current design, there are several issues that prevent you to do this:

1. You are using an object in the *stack*, i.e. not a pointer to an object allocated in the heap with `new`. Hence, it is forbidden to call `delete`.
2. The `engine` is not aware of the `car` it belongs to. Hence, in `engine::rev()`, calling `delete this;` would delete the engine, not the car. An option is to add a member `car * theCarIBelongTo` to `engine`, so that you can call `delete theCarIBelongTo;`. An other option is to have a method `car::revEngine()` that calls `Engine.rev();`, then calls `delete this;` if the temperature is too high. (so you call `Car->revEngine()` instead of `Car->Engine.rev()` )
3. Last but not least, deleting the object would not result in the pointer pointing to the object becoming `NULL`, and hence your test `Car != NULL` would still succeed. This will lead to Undefined Behaviour when deferencing it (in practice, a segfault). This is the most serious issue, mainly the reason why "comitting suicide" is often not recommended. You would need to change your design to take it into account.

Hence, even though my answer is a most direct answer to your question, I would **not** recommend you to use the "commiting suicide" paradigm in this case. Study carefully the other answers provided, they are the most useful and provides you good practices.

Answer (score 0):

"Suppose I have a car, having an engine and a radio. I want to start the radio when engine starts, and want to destroy car when engine is over a certain temperature"

start the radio when engine starts:from engine:

ok, add a radio field to engine and call the open method from engine::start

destroy car when engine is over a certain temperature

ok, when you increase the engine temperature in engine rev, after the line,

```
temperature += 2;                          /// add this line
if (  temperature > 50  ) car.destroy();
```

engine will need to have a car to destroy so make sure your engine looks like this,

```
class Engine
{
public:
    int temperature;
    car car;
    void start()
    {
        temperature = 15
    }

    void rev()
    {
        temperature += 2;
        if (  temperature > 50  ) car.destroy();
    }
}



main()
{
    Car car; 
    CAR.ENGINE.CAR = CAR;
    CAR.ENGINE.RADIO = CAR.RADIO;

    while(car!= NULL)
    {
        car.engine.rev();
    }
```

C'a froid, NON?